# How to pass variable value on mongoose object.find?

Tags: mongoose

I just want to ask, how I can pass variable into to mongoose query? I already tried this, but always got an empty result.

```
exports.persontSearch = function (req, res, search) {
PersonInfo.find({$or: [
    // {'name.first': /.*search.*/},
    // {'name.last': /.*search.*/}
    // {'name.first': {$regex: /.* + search + .*/}},
    // {'name.last': /.*search.*/}
    {'name.first': new RegExp('/.*' + search + '/.*')},
    {'name.last': /.*search.*/}
]}, function (err, person) {
    if (err) {
        winston.error(err);
        res.json(err);
    }
    res.json({
        result: person
    });
});
```

};

But if I change the `search` variable to the real value, the expected result is returned.

Please help.

BTW is there way to avoid the `new RegExp`?

Comment: Try `{$regex: search}`.

Comment: ohh thanks, got it.

Comment: @JohnnyHK ya you right i dint see this before and i commented and also the question was not closed so i commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In courtesy of [@JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk) comment on my post.
The working sample is this.

```
exports.personSearch = function (req, res, search) {
    PersonInfo.find({
        $or: [
            { 'name.first': { $regex: search } },
            { 'name.last': { $regex: search } }
        ]
    }, function (err, person) {
        if (err) {
            winston.error(err);
            res.json(err);
        }
        res.json(person);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
searchvalue = "/^abc/i";
exports.persontSearch = function (req, res, search) {
    PersonInfo.find({$or: [
         {'name.first': {$regex: searchvalue }}
    ]}, function (err, person) {
        if (err) {
            winston.error(err);
            res.json(err);
        }
        res.json({
            result: person
        });
    });
    };
```

Comment: sorry but your example is not working. So I post the right one based on the [@JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk) comment.